# React SSR is rendering html but not rendering text and html coming from rest apis. via Webpack and Nodejs server

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, server-side-rendering

Webpack file.

```
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");

const CommonWebpackConfig = {
  mode: "development",
  devtool: "inline-source-map",
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".tsx", ".ts", ".js"],
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader",
          options: {
            presets: [
              [
                "@babel/preset-env",
                {
                  targets: "defaults",
                },
              ],
              "@babel/preset-react",
            ],
          },
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        use: "ts-loader",
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/i,
        use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader']
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [
          MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
          "css-loader",
          "sass-loader"
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(jpg|jpeg|png|svg|gif|webp)$/,
        type: 'asset/resource'
      }
    ],
  },
};

module.exports = [
  {
    ...CommonWebpackConfig,
    target: "node",
    mode: 'development',
    entry: path.resolve(__dirname, "./SsrApp.tsx"),
    output: {
      clean: true,
      publicPath: "/",
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, "../dist/ssr"),
      assetModuleFilename: 'images/[hash][ext][query]',
      library: {
        type: "commonjs2",
      },
      globalObject: "this"
    },
    externals: {
      react: "react",
    },
    plugins: [
      new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
        filename: "[name].css",
      }),
    ],
  },
  {
    ...CommonWebpackConfig,
    entry: path.resolve(__dirname, "./Hydrate.tsx"),
    output: {
      clean: true,
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, "../dist/hydrate"),
      assetModuleFilename: 'images/[hash][ext][query]'
    },
    plugins: [
      new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
        filename: "[name].css",
      }),
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        scriptLoading: "defer",
        filename: 'index.html',
        template: './ssr/index.html'
      }),
    ],
  },
];
```

SSR Server file

```
const express = require("express");
const fs = require("fs");
const ReactDOMServer = require("react-dom/server");
const React = require("react");
const App = require("../dist/ssr/main.js");

const app = express();

const htmlPageContent = fs.readFileSync("./dist/hydrate/index.html", "utf8");

app.use(express.static("dist/hydrate", { index: false }));

app.get("*", (req, res) => {

  const html = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(App.SsrApp(req.url));

  const finalHtml = htmlPageContent.replace(
    '<div id="root"></div>',
    `<div id="root">${html}</div>`
  );
  res.send(finalHtml);
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log("SRR Server is listening on port http://localhost:3000/");
});
```

SSRApp.tsx

```
import { StaticRouter } from "react-router-dom/server";

export const SsrApp = (pathname: string) => {
  return (
    <StaticRouter location={pathname}>
      <App />
    </StaticRouter>
  );
};
```

Hydrate.tsx

```
import * as React from "react";
import { hydrateRoot } from "react-dom/client";
import App from "../src/App";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import "../src/index.css";
import { SnackbarProvider } from "notistack";
import "animate.css";
import "../src/index.css";
import "../src/assets/template/css/styles.min.css";

hydrateRoot(
  document.getElementById("root") as HTMLElement,
  <BrowserRouter>
    <SnackbarProvider maxSnack={3} autoHideDuration={3000}>
      <App />
    </SnackbarProvider>
  </BrowserRouter>
);
```

problem is everything working fine in browser. but hardcoded text in my files is renderring fine in browsers source page. but text and data coming from apis does not render in source page

in browser view page this text is showing up fine. as it si coming from apis.
[image]

but in source page its not there. so problem in webpack configuration it does not prerender the data from apis and then it should render whole page in browser.
when i inspect to view source page its not there. so not good for SEO.
[image]